# Django Login in context processor doesn't work properly

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views, django-templates

I tried to display login and registration form on all my Django app.
For that I use context_processor that ad login form in context.

This is my context_processors.py in app:

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect("myapp:user_page")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return {"login_form": form}
```

I then call processors in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'myapp.context_processors.login_request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And finally I use declared form in a modal in my base.html template:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
                    SignIn
                </button>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                     aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h1>Login</h1>
                                <form method="POST">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {{ login_form }}
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button> 
                                </form>
                                <p class="text-center">Forget Password? <a
                                        href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Change password</a>.
                                </p>
                                <p class="text-center">Don't have an account? <a
                                        href="#registerModal">Create an
                                    account</a>.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But each time I tried to submit the form I got the following error:

> dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

I can't find where does exactly the problem come from, as I got the same problem with the register form which is used the same way.

Comment: I think I answered my own question, problem come from the fact that both my login and register function use a redirect ("myapp.views_function") while context-processor can only return context dictionnary

Answer (score 0):

Solve my problem, by replacing my return redirect after form validation. Context processor are not supposed to receive redirect to another template function

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return (request,{user})
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return {"login_form": form}
```